# Создание статических ссылок для Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, servlet, tomcat

Создал сервер под Tomcat, задача которого помещать определенные xml в очередь сообщений. Выбор xml'я реализовал в соответствующем классе в зависимости от типа ссылки полученной от сервлета 'HttpServletRequest request'
    String link = request.getRequestURl();
Но сервлет у меня один и ссылка которая получилась имеет формат 
http://localhost:8080/{Project_Name}/{ServletName}
У меня же двадцать типов разных xml, то есть нужно сделать как то 20 разных типов ссылок. Каким образом их сгенерировать и где?

Comment: чем вызвано использование `request.getRequestURl()`?

Comment: @RomanC получаю оттуда ссылку в стринге, далее есть реализация выбора xml файла в зависимости от наличия определенных слов в запросе, который будет отсылаться LoadRunner'ом.

Comment: напишите пример использования в коде

Comment: String link = request.getRequestURI();
  XMLCreator xml = new XMLCreator(link);    
  SenderToMQ sender = new SenderToMQ(xml);

Comment: public class XMLCreator {
 /*public static void main (String args[]) {
  XMLCreator xml = new XMLCreator();
  xml.selectXML();
 }*/
 
 public XMLCreator(String link) {
  if (link.contains("Cnfrm")) {
   transformateXML1();
  }
  if (link.contains("Container")) {
   transformateXML2();
  }
  if (link.contains("VVinq")) {
   transformateXML4();
  }
  if (link.contains("VVdvrvInq")) {
   transformateXML5();
  }